# Angular wrapper component takes additional directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that looks something like the following:

```
.directive('textInput', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: false,
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      var html =
      '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<label>{{ \'' + attrs.label + '\' | translate }}</label>' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="' + attrs.placeholder +
        '" ng-model="' + attrs.ngModel + '"' + attrs.directives + '>' +
      '</div>';

      var newElem = $(html);
      element.replaceWith(newElem);

      return function (scope, element, attrs, controller) { };
    }
  };
})
```

Note that the `directives` attribute was a string that added additional attribute information (e.g. tooltip info)

I have converted it to a 1.5 `component` but I'm not able to do the same with the `directives` definition.

```
.component('textInput', {
  bindings: {
    label: '@',
    placeholder: '@',
    directives: '<',
    ngModel: '='
  },
  require: {
    ngModelCtrl: 'ngModel'
  },
  template:
    '<div class="form-group">' +
      '<label ng-if="$ctrl.label">{{$ctrl.label | translate }}</label>' +
      '<input' +
        ' type="text"' +
        ' class="form-control input-sm"' +
        ' placeholder="{{$ctrl.placeholder}}"' +
        ' ng-model="$ctrl.ngModel"' +
        ' {{$ctrl.directives}}>' +
    '</div>'
})

<text-input directives="tooltip='foobar'"></text-input>
```

How can I pass in a string to the `<text-input/>` element such that the underlying template gets the correct information?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, according to the docs,:

> When not to use Components:
>
> for directives that rely on DOM manipulation, adding event listeners
>   etc, because the compile and link functions are unavailable when you
>   need advanced directive definition options like priority, terminal,
>   multi-element when you want a directive that is triggered by an
>   attribute or CSS class, rather than an element

and in the same page it says that components doesn't have `compile` function.